# How to convert this list of characters into a mutableListOf<String>() in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have downloaded a file as follows:

```
var list = File("src/resources/words_threeLetters.txt").readText()
```

`print(list)` produces the following ...

```
[aaa, aah, aal, aam, aas, aba, abb, abc, abd . . . etc
```

But `print(list[0])` results in "[" 
and `print(list[1])` results in "a"

Is there a straight forward way to convert what appears to be this list of characters posing as words into a list of words in a `mutableListOf<String>()`?

I have tried to declare the variable `list` as a Kotlin `mutableListOf<String>` and `mutableListOf<Char>` before downloading. Both failed.

Comment: As the documentation shows, readText() doesn't return a List. it returns a String: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-text.html. Trying to declare the variable as a type other than String won't change what readText() returns: a String. You need to **parse** this String.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a file will return `String` [readText](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-text.html).

You need to parse that `String` in order to convert into your collection.

```
var list = File("src/resources/words_threeLetters.txt").readText()
// Use your own parsing; Here I'm just splitting the String with comma delimiter.
var list: MutableList<String> = fileText?.split(",").toMutableList()
```

Comment: I now understand. Your clear reply was very helpful and much appreciated.